# In SugarCRM having comma as decimal separator, how to save decimal value of a field?

Tags: c#, web-services, sugarcrm

**Scenario**

> Update opportunity amount in sugar from c#

**Problem**

> When opportunity amount is in decimal and sugar is having comma (,)
>   as decimal separator. the amount is saved incorrectly (500.50 is saved
>   as 50050)

The only was to do this is to read the sugar settings. But there is no such method in soap.php which returns number separators

P.S. Interestingly when value is read from sugar, it gives with dot as separator. which is then rightly read in c#. the problem lies only in writing value to sugar.

Comment: http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/removing-default-currency-separator-47318/